# How to show "Set program associations" window in Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: c#, c++, file-association, default-programs

I want to show `Set program associations` windows *[edit: for my program]* like Chrome do when it run first time after install, like this:

[image]

It have:

- Name of my program
- File types I want to set default program (more than one)

How to do it by c# (or win32 c++)?

**Edit**
I read some articles about modify registry (by .reg file or by code work around modify registry) to set default program. It seem only work in Windows XP/7 or lower, not 8/8.1 as Microsoft use hash to protect these registry.

Comment: Try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-rundll32exe-and-why-is-it-running/

Comment: Are you asking how to offer your program as a possible default for those extensions, or how to launch the GUI to let the user choose defaults?

Comment: Yes, I want to offer my program as a possible default for some extensions. I read about set by registry. It work for me in windows XP and 7 but it seem don't work any more in Windows 8.1, as Windows use hash to check when modify a default program association.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all explained in the official documentation here: [Guidelines for File Associations and Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ee872123.aspx)

To launch this Windows-provided UI, you can use the [IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb776329.aspx) interface.

Here is a sample console app that demonstrate this for a fictional "MyApp" application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI app = (IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI)new ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI();
        int hr = app.LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI("MyApp");
        Exception error = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error.Message);
        }
    }
}

[Guid("1f76a169-f994-40ac-8fc8-0959e8874710")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszAppRegName);
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("1968106d-f3b5-44cf-890e-116fcb9ecef1")]
public class ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI
{
}
```

And this is not finished :-) This only works if the registry is properly setup for this "MyApp" application, which is kinda the difficult part. Here are the simplest steps needed for this to work:

1) create a fictional "MyAppHTML" progid in HKCR, like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAppHTML]
@="MyApp HTML Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAppHTML\Application]
"ApplicationCompany"="Fictional Software Inc."

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAppHTML\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAppHTML\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyAppHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\the app path\\testassoc.exe\""
```

2) declare a fictional "MyApp" application (I suggest HKCU, but it could be HKLM), from a fictional "FictionalSoftware" company, like this, for example with two file associations:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FictionalSoftware]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FictionalSoftware\MyApp]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FictionalSoftware\MyApp\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="My Fictional Application"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FictionalSoftware\MyApp\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".htm"="MyAppHTML"
".html"="MyAppHTML"
```

3) register this application to Windows (again, HKCU could be replaced by HKLM), like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RegisteredApplications]
"MyApp"="Software\\FictionalSoftware\\MyApp\\Capabilities"
```

If you get errors when running the sample app, then you probably messed up the registry layout. If you got it ok, then you should see something like this:

[image]